# google maps api with the name of the place

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to use the Google Maps web service.

When directly in my browser I am entering this
[URI](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=cookoo%2012%20rue%20de%20Rieux%2044000%20Nantes%20France&sensor=false)
I get a LOCATION_TYPE which is APPROXIMATIVE with "formatted_address" : "44000 Nantes, France",

And if I enter
[this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=12%20rue%20de%20Rieux%2044000%20Nantes%20France&sensor=false)
 I get a good result with a location type : rooftop...

But when I enter the same address in google maps (maps.google.com) Cookoo, 12 Rue de Rieux, Nantes, there is no problem google maps find the place with no issue...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The entry "Cookoo, 12 Rue de Rieux 44000 Nantes France" is in the Places database, but not in the Geocoder database; you can get that result by querying the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/)

Enter the string above in the search box on this [test page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxB.html)

Comment: Thanks !!! But I thought the places API was expecting a lattitude and a longitude parameters ?

Comment: There are lots of interfaces to Places data, in the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/), Search, AutoComplete, etc., there is also support for queries built into the Google Maps API v3.

Answer (score 0):

I think the geocoder in the Google Maps API is just for addresses, so when you add in a business name like 'Cookoo', that will throw it off a little. To search businesses, you might try the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/), which is supposed to look up this information.

Google Maps the website, on the other hand, is product that combines a lot of services, so it can do the business search as well as handle the address.

Maybe your workflow could be
Address --> Geocoder --> Lat/Lon --> Places